# SUMIFS Using Multiple Ranges?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

In the screenshot below, columns A-B are on one tab, D-F are on another, and finally H is on a tab of it's own. Columns A-B is a tab that I use to tally worked hours by each employee less any time spent on PM tickets (Column H).

[image: Screenshot of Sample Data]

I am wanting to populate B2 with all hours worked (F) by "Rob" (A2) where his job tickets (E) do not match any of the PM tickets (H).

I can sum the hours by name with SUMIF or cross-compare the job tickets with SUMIFS but I cannot seem to manage to do both in the same formula.

If it matters, the actual D-F and H data is ~500 rows long. Also, I am working in Google Sheets and not Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B2`, copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$10=A2)*ISNA(MATCH($E$2:$E$10,$H$2:$H$10,0))*$F$2:$F$10)
```

[image]

Comment: Bosco - Thank you very much, I have accepted your answer. How difficult would it be to reverse this to SUM only the hours where the Job Ticket (E) does match the PM Tickets (H)?

Comment: The reverse formula in B2 is : =SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$10=A2)*ISNUMBER(MATCH($E$2:$E$10,$H$2:$H$10,0))*$F$2:$F$10) then copied down